# Manipulating a multidimensional set: marginalization, extension, membership

Tags: python, python-2.7, set, python-itertools

I'm doing a python module that requires lots of set manipulations. I have tried lots of things but I haven't succeded. First, I'm dealing with  sets in three dimensions and then I use itertools product function to do the cartesian product:

```
from itertools import product

# Marginal sets
x1 = set(['u1', 'd1'])
x2 = set(['u2', 'd2'])
x3 = set(['u3', 'd3'])

# Cartesian product of x1,x2,x3
X = set(product(x1,x2,x3))

>>> X
set([('d1', 'u2', 'u3'), ('u1', 'u2', 'u3'), ('u1', 'u2', 'd3'), ('d1', 'd2', 'u3'), ('u1', 'd2', 'd3'), ('d1', 'd2', 'd3'), ('u1', 'd2', 'u3'), ('d1', 'u2', 'd3')])
```

I would like to extend set intersection such that it accepts the following:

```
>>>set('d1') & X # Return elements of X containing 'd1'
set([('d1', 'u2', 'u3'), ('d1', 'd2', 'u3'), ('d1', 'd2', 'd3'), ('d1', 'u2', 'd3')])
```

And also the following:

```
>>>set('d1','u2') & X # Return elements of X containing 'd1'
set([('d1', 'u2', 'u3'), ('d1', 'u2', 'd3')])
```

I would also like to extend again the cartesian product by adding a new dimension, e.g.

```
x4 = set(['u4', 'd4'])
Y = cartesianproduct(X,x4)
>>>Y
set([('u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'd4'), ('d1', 'd2', 'u3', 'd4'), ('u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'u4'), ('u1', 'u2', 'd3', 'u4'), ('d1', 'u2', 'u3', 'u4'), ('d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'u4'), ('d1', 'd2', 'u3', 'u4'), ('d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4'), ('u1', 'u2', 'd3', 'd4'), ('u1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4'), ('d1', 'u2', 'd3', 'd4'), ('d1', 'u2', 'd3', 'u4'), ('u1', 'd2', 'u3', 'u4'), ('d1', 'u2', 'u3', 'd4'), ('u1', 'd2', 'd3', 'u4'), ('u1', 'd2', 'u3', 'd4')])
```

Finally, I would like to remove a dimension:

```
Z = remove(x3,X)
>>>Z
set([('d1', 'd2'), ('u1', 'u2'), ('u1', 'd2'), ('d1', 'u2')])
```

I'm new in Python and I feel like I'm doing it totally wrong, mixing lists, tuples and sets in the wrong ways maybe...

Please be gentle :)

Comment: This is not a question about Cartesian products, as that's just a way to *create* the initial data. The *problem* is purely about how to manipulate the set that results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would work with a list of sets instead:

```
X = map(set,product(x1,x2,x3))

def has_element(X,Y):
    return [y for y in Y if len(y.intersection(X))]

print has_element(['d1','u1'],X)

>>> [set(['d2', 'u1', 'd3']), set(['d2', 'u1', 'u3']), set(['u1', 'd3', 'u2']), set(['u1', 'u3', 'u2']), set(['d2', 'd3', 'd1']), set(['d2', 'u3', 'd1']), set(['u2', 'd3', 'd1']), set(['u2', 'u3', 'd1'])]
```

For your second function:

```
def new_product(X,Y):
    Z = []
    for a,b in product(X,Y):
        ab = b.copy()
        ab.add(a)
        Z.append(ab)
    return Z

print new_product(set(['d4','u4']),X)

>>> [set(['u1', 'd2', 'd3', 'u4']), set(['u1', 'd2', 'u3', 'u4']), set(['u4', 'u1', 'd3', 'u2']), set(['u4', 'u1', 'u3', 'u2']), set(['u4', 'd2', 'd3', 'd1']), set(['u4', 'd2', 'u3', 'd1']), set(['u4', 'd1', 'd3', 'u2']), set(['u4', 'd1', 'u3', 'u2']), set(['u1', 'd4', 'd2', 'd3']), set(['u1', 'd4', 'd2', 'u3']), set(['d4', 'u1', 'd3', 'u2']), set(['d4', 'u1', 'u3', 'u2']), set(['d4', 'd2', 'd3', 'd1']), set(['d4', 'd2', 'u3', 'd1']), set(['d4', 'd1', 'd3', 'u2']), set(['d4', 'd1', 'u3', 'u2'])]
```

The final function:

```
def remove(X,Y):
    Z = Y[:] # Make a copy
    for z in Z:
        for x in X:
            if x in z:
                z.remove(x)
    return Z

print remove(x3,X)

>>> [set(['d2', 'd1']), set(['d2', 'd1']), set(['u2', 'd1']), set(['u2', 'd1'])]
```

Comment: I edited the original question, I forgot to mention that I also need has_element(('d1','u2'),X) to work in a similar way...

Comment: @FelipeAguirre Updated the answer to work with your requirement. Just note that now you can't pass in a single argument, it has to be wrapped in a iterable object. Use the backticks to write inline code in comments \`this\` becomes `this`.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough, the expected output of `has_element(('d1','u2'),X)` is to return elements that have `'d1'` AND `'u2'`. Your solution returns elements that have `'d1'` OR `'u2'`

Comment: @FelipeAguirre That's an easy fix! Just change the part that says `len(y.intersection(X))` to `len(y.intersection(X))==len(X)` which will require you to match all of the elements not just one.